# python script command line arguments from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

test.txt

```
port = 1234

host = abc.com
```

test.py

```
port = sys.argv[1]

host = sys.argv[2]
```

I want to provide test.txt as input to python script:

```
python test.py test.txt
```

so that , port and host values in text file should pass as command line arguments to python script which are inturn passed to port and host in the script.

if i do :

python test.py 1234 abc.com

the arguments are passed to sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2]

the same i want to achieve using reading from txt file.

Thanks.

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: i want solution, how to do it. modified my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a `test.txt` file with a section header:

```
[settings]
port = 1234
host = abc.com
```

You could use the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) library to get the host and port content:

```
import sys
import ConfigParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(sys.argv[1])
    print config['settings']['host']
    print config['settings']['port']
```

In Python 3 it's called [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) (lowercase).

Comment: This worked with small change: config.get("settings","appport"). Thanks.

Comment: @lgor Hatarist I am getting "IndexError: list index out of range" error, if I run the above script. Unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Kumar It's because when you run it, you don't pass an argument to the command. Run it using `python script.py test.txt`, not just `python script.py`. You could figure it out by reading about [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) in the python's documentation).

Answer (score 1):

A way to do so in Linux is to do:

```
 awk '{print $3}' test.txt | xargs python test.py
```

Your .txt file can be separated in 3 columns, of which the 3rd contains the values for port and host. `awk '{print $3}'` extracts those column and `xargs` feeds them as input parameters to your python script.

Of course, that is only if you don't want to modify your .py script to read the file and extract those input values.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead just write the text file as:

```
1234
abc.com
```

Then you can do this:

```
input_file = open(sys.argv[1])
port = int(input_file.readLine())
host = input_file.readLine()
```

Comment: This also worked but after replacing port value in a file, the rest of string in the line of file is moving to next line. But, thanks though.